# Что означает true?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

У меня есть такой файл in.pl:

```
in_array([X],X):-true.
in_array([H|Tail],H):-true.
in_array([_|Tail],H):-in_array(Tail,H).
```

Запускаю GNU prolog:

```
| ?- [in].
in_array([1,2],2).
true ? 
yes
```

Нажимаю Enter, отвечает yes. Зачем он спрашивает про "true ?"

Comment: Вообще-то prolog, а не lisp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true` означает что элемент в списке есть, а `yes` - что возможны еще варианты (например если элемент там встречается не один раз). Варианты просматриваются нажатием "точки с запятой". Если вариантов больше нет, то после нажатия `;` он выведет `no`.

Вообще первая строка в принципе не нужна, получается, что он найдет двойку по первой строке, а потом по второй.

И выражения вида `in_array(...):-true.` можно заменить просто на `in_array(...).`